# Custom action message can't be found during compilation

Tags: ros-melodic, action, catkin, message, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I created a custom action message, under the laser_line_extraction/action folder:

CornerExtractionAction.action:

```
#goal definition
bool flag
---
#result definition
geometry_msgs/Point[] points
---
#feedback
geometry_msgs/Point[] points
```

by which I include it in my executables .cpp as such:

```
#include <laser_line_extraction/CornerExtractionAction.h>
```

also tried as:

```
#include "laser_line_extraction/CornerExtractionAction.h"
```

but when I run catkin build, I get this error message and I couldn't figure out yet what's the problem.

```
/home/alexnic/conbotics/src/cb_spraybase/cb_perception/laser_line_extraction/src/corner_action_client.cpp:4:10: fatal error: laser_line_extraction/CornerExtractionAction.h: No such file or directory
 #include <laser_line_extraction/CornerExtractionAction.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/corner_action_client.dir/src/corner_action_client.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/corner_action_client.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/home/alexnic/conbotics/src/cb_spraybase/cb_perception/laser_line_extraction/src/corner_action_server.cpp:10:10: fatal error: laser_line_extraction/CornerExtractionAction.h: No such file or directory
 #include <laser_line_extraction/CornerExtractionAction.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/corner_action_server.dir/src/corner_action_server.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/corner_action_server.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I also tried with deleting devel and build folder but yet the problem exist.
I'll also post relevant files for your reference. I would appreciate it if anyone identifies my mistake. Thank you in advance.
(Running on ROS1 melodic)

CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(laser_line_extraction)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cmake_modules
  geometry_msgs
  roscpp
  rospy
  sensor_msgs
  visualization_msgs
  geometry_msgs
  message_generation
  actionlib_msgs
  actionlib
)

find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)

add_message_files(
  FILES
  LineSegment.msg
  LineSegmentList.msg
)

add_service_files(
  FILES
  CornerExtraction.srv
)

add_action_files(
  DIRECTORY action
  FILES CornerExtractionAction.action
)

generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  sensor_msgs
  geometry_msgs
  actionlib
  actionlib_msgs
)



catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES line line_extraction line_extraction_ros
  CATKIN_DEPENDS geometry_msgs message_runtime roscpp sensor_msgs visualization_msgs actionlib_msgs actionlib
)

add_library(line src/line.cpp)
target_link_libraries(line ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_library(line_extraction src/line_extraction.cpp)
target_link_libraries(line_extraction ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_library(line_extraction_ros src/line_extraction_ros.cpp)
target_link_libraries(line_extraction_ros line line_extraction ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(line_extraction_ros laser_line_extraction_generate_messages_cpp)

add_executable(line_extraction_node src/line_extraction_node.cpp)
target_link_libraries(line_extraction_node line_extraction_ros ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(corner_extraction src/corner_extraction.cpp)
target_link_libraries(corner_extraction line_extraction_ros ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(line_server src/line_server.cpp)
target_link_libraries(line_server ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(line_server laser_line_extraction_gencpp)

add_executable(corner_client src/corner_client.cpp)
target_link_libraries(corner_client ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(corner_client laser_line_extraction_gencpp)

add_executable(corner_action_server src/corner_action_server.cpp)
target_link_libraries(corner_action_server ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
# add_dependencies(corner_action_server ${laser_line_extraction_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
add_dependencies(corner_action_server laser_line_extraction_generate_messages_cpp)


add_executable(corner_action_client src/corner_action_client.cpp)
target_link_libraries(corner_action_client ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
# add_dependencies(corner_action_client ${laser_line_extraction_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
add_dependencies(corner_action_client laser_line_extraction_generate_messages_cpp)

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(include ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_laser_line_extraction.cpp)

install(TARGETS line_extraction_node RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})
install(TARGETS line_extraction_ros line_extraction line ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION} LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION} RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_GLOBAL_BIN_DESTINATION})
install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/ DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION})
```

I tried also with:

```
add_dependencies(corner_action_server ${laser_line_extraction_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
add_dependencies(corner_action_client ${laser_line_extraction_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

And package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>laser_line_extraction</name>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
  <description>
      A ROS package to extract line segments from LaserScan messages.
  </description>
  <maintainer email="m.gallant@queensu.ca">Marc Gallant</maintainer>
  <license>BSD</license>
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>cmake_modules</build_depend>
  <build_depend>eigen</build_depend>
  <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>sensor_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>visualization_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>actionlib</build_depend>
  <build_depend>actionlib_msgs</build_depend>
  <run_depend>geometry_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>sensor_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>visualization_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>geometry_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>actionlib</run_depend>
  <run_depend>actionlib_msgs</run_depend>

</package>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377309/custom-action-message-can%27t-be-found-during-compilation/) by [AlexandrosNic](https://answers.ros.org/users/45283/alexandrosnic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 233 on 2021-04-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abhishek47](https://answers.ros.org/users/34260/abhishek47/) on 2021-04-30**:
Are you sure you've followed all the steps in [creating action messages](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionServer%28ExecuteCallbackMethod%29#Creating_the_Action_Messages) and [compiling the action](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionServer%28ExecuteCallbackMethod%29#Compiling)?

Also, the action file has a `bool` which is a `std_msgs`; in CMakeLists perhaps you should add that in `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)`?

**Comment by [AlexandrosNic](https://answers.ros.org/users/45283/alexandrosnic/) on 2021-04-30**:
Actually indeed the problem was that I forgot to define the std_msgs.
I also added <run_depend>message_generation</run_depend> in the package.xml file.
Thank you for your answer

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-04-30**:
Congratulations. If you like, you can write your own answer and check the box for resolution. It will help others who follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed it through your recommendations. First I forgot to define the std_msgs (for the boolean) and include them in the package.xml. Second, I added <run_depend>message_generation</run_depend> in the package.xml file.
Thank you for your replies.

---

Originally posted by [AlexandrosNic](https://answers.ros.org/users/45283/alexandrosnic/) with karma: 233 on 2021-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0